# How can I fix NewtonSoft (json.net) errors after Xamarin update?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, json.net

I'm using Xamarin (just upgraded) with Visual Studio 2015. The Windows computer is connected to a Mac. The ios app has Newtonsoft.Json.dll library included, version 6.0.0.0 .

I've tried to change the Linker Behavior settings , the versions of Newtonsoft library but after Xamarin update,I get this error:

> Failed to resolve "System.Void
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver::set_IgnoreSerializableAttribute(System.Boolean)"
>   reference from "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"

Even if I change the library version, the error is referring at the version 6.0.0.0. And in the solution I have both

> portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+monotouch+monoandroid

and

> portable-net45+wp80+win8

folders.

Have you had problems with this library using Xamarin? Do you have any idea about how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall and reinstall the Json.net Nuget.

Comment: I already did it for ios project and the error is still there. A reference to this library exists in the PCL project, and I cannot uninstall it from there. The error is the same, plus
`Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`